# update geometry of a mesh with other vertices in THREE.JS

Tags: javascript, three.js, mesh

I have several meshes, with about 5000 vertices each. these are the original vertices and call "verticesA" the problem is that it is delayed to run the following line:

```
shapeFigure[x] = new THREE.Shape (geometry [x] .vertices); // Very slow.
```

then transformed "shape [x]" in a mesh.

```
shape[x] = new THREE.ShapeGeometry( shapeFigure[x][x] );
mesh[x] = new THREE.Mesh (shape[x], new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial ({color: "# FF0000"}));
```

this is obvious because they are many mesh with many vertices. I have a button in my alplicación which generates an algorithm. This algorithm ONLY generates new vertices (I'll call verticesB, these vertices have the same length as the "verticesA"). I want to update the "verticesA" with "verticesB".

how I can update the "verticesA" that figure is in the form of "verticesB".
I do not want to use again "`new THREE.Shape` ..." because it is delayed (because I have many mesh with many vertices). I want to directly update verticesA TO verticesB, (it is faster)

I'm doing something like this:

```
//mesh-> is the original (verticesA)

http://imgur.com/ympHorb (verticesA)

//geometry[x]-> is a array with the new vertices (verticesB)

//geometry[x] and mesh[x] is the same length of vertices

for (var a in mesh[x].geometry.vertices) {
 mesh[x].geometry.vertices[a].x=geometry[x][a].x;
 mesh[x].geometry.vertices[a].y=geometry[x][a].y;
}
```

In my function `render()`, i have:

```
for (var t in mesh){

  mesh[t].geometry.verticesNeedUpdate=true;
  mesh[t].geometry.dynamic = true;
}
```

this is a map, but after running the above code and is updated but is distorted.the problem is that is not properly updated geometry.

```
http://imgur.com/qCWoMWe
```

the map should be this way:

```
http://imgur.com/MYXzaEd (this is verticesB)
```

how I can update the geometry correctly?

Comment: Are you using ShapeGeometry or ExtrudeGeometry to create mesh? Are you sure your points are in correct order?

Comment: @uhura I'm not using any of those you say.
"new THREE.Shape" and then "new THREE.Mesh"..

Comment: I didn't find in documentation or examples that you can use new THREE.Shape as geometry and when I tried to make example I got error. How it's working?

Comment: @uhura excuse me!. yeah, I was using "new THREE.ShapeGeometry" I updated the post code. then you understand what I want?

Comment: Are you sure generated verticesB are in correct order? Did you try to create shape with them (not to update vertices)? Is shape distorted just when you try to update vertices?

Comment: when I try to update verticesA to verticesB i have : http://imgur.com/qCWoMWe   :(

Comment: yes, I'm sure they are in the correct order. verticesB to verticesA and have the same number of vertices. and verticesB shown so often. imgur.com/MYXzaEd

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91430/discussion-between-yavg-and-uhura).